# Jackson - infinite loops deserializing

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using jackson to deserialize following json content:

```
{
 "contacts": [
    {
      "localId": 45,
      "serverId": 0,
      "numbers": [
        "1111",
        "2222"
      ]
    },
    {
      "localId": 11,
      "serverId": 0,
      "numbers": [
        "5555"
      ]
    }
   ]
}
```

My Java classes are

```
public class Contacts implements Serializable {

    private List<Contact> contacts;

    ... public Getter and Setter here

}
```

and

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ContactSerializer.class)
public class Contact implements Serializable {

    public long server_id;
    public long local_id;
    public List<String> numbers;

     ... public Getter and Setter here
}
```

There is no reference from Contact to Contacts. There are some additional attributes in Contact which are not serialized on the way to the server (request) and not send back from the server (response). I excluded them by  using  @JsonIgnore.
I receive the json mentioned above as answer from the server. But when deserializing it there will be a infinite loop and the programm terminates.
I tried to use a deserializer for Contact, but it had the same result. It ended in a infinite loop inside Contact.

EDIT: The method call from the app:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 Contacts c = mapper.readValue(result.getResult(), Contacts.class);
```

EDIT: The Serializer

```
public class ContactSerializer extends StdSerializer<Contact> {

    protected ContactSerializer() {
        super(Contact.class);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void serialize(Contact value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {

        jgen.writeStartObject();

        jgen.writeNumberField(Contact.COLUMN_LOCAL_ID, value.getLocalId());
        jgen.writeNumberField(Contact.COLUMN_SERVER_ID, value.getServerId());
        jgen.writeObjectField(Contact.COLUMN_NUMBERS, value.getNumbers());

        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: share ContactSerializer code

Comment: @Amer Qarabsa: I added the serializer

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the code you shared, I guess it's somewhere else caused your bug.

Comment: For me too, I copy/paste your code and no error happen.

Comment: Hmm.. There are some additional methods in Contact and some constants. They may not cause theese problems? Also, @JsonIgnore is just on the attributes not on their setters/getters.

Comment: I debugged throw the CollectionDeserializer class.

In the method 

 public Collection<Object> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt,
      Collection<Object> result)
  throws IOException, JsonProcessingException

is a loop that steps throw all entries until it finds the end of the array

  JsonToken t;
  while ((t = jp.nextToken()) != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {

  ..}

The first two elements are fine, but then "t" is always null.

Comment: It appears that  I copied not the complete value from my debugger. Sorry. There is also one entry  {
      "localId": 12,
      "serverId": 0,
      "numbers": null;
    }     

Is it a problem, that number array may be null?